# time complexity issue when checking the connectivity between nodes in R igraph

Tags: r, performance, time-complexity, igraph, graph-theory

I'd like to see which first degree nodes are connected to which second degree nodes for every node in a given graph. Suppose I generate a graph with 1000 nodes.

```
library(igraph)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(1000, 0.2)
```

When I calculate the set of adjacent nodes and second degree nodes for every node in the graph, there's no issue.

The code runs pretty quick independent from the size of the network. Once I add an `if` statement to check if two nodes are connected as:

```
for(j in adjacent){
      for(k in secondDegreNodes){
             if(  are.connected(g, j, k) ){

             }
         }
      }
```

My code takes forever. What is the exact complexity issue that I am facing? Is there a better way to conduct this operation?

There is something odd definetely happening. Even the following code block does not converge though it's the simplest operation.

```
g <- erdos.renyi.game(1000, 0.3)
A <- as_adjacency_matrix(g)
from<- 1
to <- nrow(A)
for(i in from:to){
  for(j in i:to){
    if(A[i,j] == 1){
      #do nothing
    }

  }
}
```

EDIT: I believe there could be some issues with igraph package. I generated the graph in R igraph and coded everything in Java language, and it worked. As I expected, there is no complexity issue with the algorithm. However, I have no idea what is wrong with igraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example that you give, indexing matrix `A` repeatedly in a for-loop is rather inefficient. In this particular instance it is due to `A` being of class `dgCMatrix` from package *Matrix*.

When you compare the performance before and after converting `A` to another class, you will notice the difference. With `N = 300` nodes, the duration of the for-loop decreases from 23.5 seconds to 0.1 seconds on my machine once I convert to the standard matrix class. There are moreover (N^2 + N) / 2 comparisons to be made. The squared term means going from 300 nodes to 3 x 300 = 900 nodes will roughly increase the computing time ninefold (at the very least).

If you further `Rprof`ile the code, you will see that when subsetting an object of class `dgCMatrix` (i.e. `A[i, j]`) a number of further R functions are called, whereas the function `[` is implemented straight in C for the basic matrix class. In addition, `dgCMatrix` is from the S4 object system. That means i.a. that finding the right method to use for `[` is a little more costly than usual.

Finally, if you rely on R, you will be much better of (in general) using **vectorised operations**. These will typically avoid a deep call stack of further (inefficient) R functions and will often be implemented in C. With the adjacency matrix, you can quickly find second degree nodes by inspecting `A_2 = A %*% A` which will be very fast also (or I suspect especially so) for an object of class `dgCMatrix`.

---

Timing:

```
library(igraph)

N <- 300
g <- erdos.renyi.game(N, 0.3)
A <- as_adjacency_matrix(g)
from<- 1
to <- nrow(A)

class(A)
# [1] "dgCMatrix"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "Matrix"

# run through matrix via for loop
# 23.5 seconds
system.time({
  for(i in from:to){
    for(j in i:to){
      if(A[i,j] == 1) {}
    }
  }
})

# change class
A <- as.matrix(A)

class(A)
# [1] "matrix"

# run for loop again
# 0.097 seconds
system.time({
  for(i in from:to){
    for(j in i:to){
      if(A[i,j] == 1) {}
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the great detailed explanation. It is quite informative. However, my main question still stays the same. When I call ```are.connected(g, j, k)``` to check if there exists an edge between two given nodes, my algorithm does not run efficiently. I added the example of matrix A to emphasize the issue that I was facing. To sum up, my problem is more related to igraph. Having said that, If I use the conversion that you suggested, I might do what I intended to do.